# Prove or disprove that random process $\underline{z}(t) = \underline{x}_n$ where $nT \leq t < (n+1)T$ is WSS

Tags: self-study, random-variable, stationarity

Given that $\underline{x}_n$ is a random sequences consists of independent RVs with $mean=0$ and $var=1$. Then form the process:

\begin{align}
\underline{z}(t) = \underline{x}_n \quad where \quad nT \leq t < (n+1)T
\end{align}

Given T is a positive constant. Then can we prove or disprove that $\underline{z}(t)$ is WSS?

Comment: as $E(\underline{z}(t)) = E(\underline{x}) = 0$ already, we will need to prove that the autocorrelation $R(\tau)$ only depends on $\tau$ or not, however I have no idea how to continue

Comment: I'll reopen the thread, but all you need is an immediate application of the definition of WSS, without any calculation, to answer the question in the negative: just compare the covariance of $\underline{z}_0$ and $\underline{z}_{T}$ to the covariance of $\underline{z}_0$ and $\underline{z}_{T/2}.$

Comment: @whuber I tried comparing $\underline{z}_0$ and $\underline{z}_{T/2}$, then $\underline{z}_{T/2}$ and $\underline{z}_{T}$. It’s obvious that the results are different for the same $\tau=T/2$, but I’m not sure because it looks overly simple.